# How to stop executing FOR loop until code is completed

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, for-loop

I made this thing. It has no purpose other than for demonstration to myself. Essentially, I'm moving a view that I created around the screen in a loop. The problem is that it doesn't wait until it's done with one animation before starting the other, and so the view bypasses the first two and ends up at the last `toastRect` after the for loop is done, and it doesn't keep moving after that. How can I force the code to complete each animation before moving on to the next?

```
int i;
    for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:9];
        toast.view.frame = toastRect1;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:9];
        toast.view.frame = toastRect2;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:9];
        toast.view.frame = toastRect;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        NSLog(@"%d",i);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `+ (void)setAnimationDidStopSelector:(SEL)selector`. Take a closer look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html if you want.

Comment: Thanks! That made the code a bit more complicated, but it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setAnimationDidStopSelector` method to *chain* the animations. Check the docs for details: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDidStopSelector: